# Access denied when using findstr windows command

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8

I'm running a windows batch file containing the following command: `echo ABC | findstr A` which returns Access denied when executed in a specific folder.

I copied and executed the file in any random folder and it returned the result correctly, there is one specific folder from which the execution will return access denied, I checked the Security configuration for the folder and everything is identical to the configuration of other folders, please any insights?

Comment: Please provide more of the batch file content, run it directly in a Command Prompt window, with `Echo On` and paste the content of the window into another code box too, by [Edit]ing your question.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the folder has its own copy of `findstr.exe` which you are running by mistake.